# How to Catch an Error While Establishing Remote Connection in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling, sh, openssh

This is how part of my shell script looks like.

```
#! /bin/sh
sftp -i $IdentityFile $ServerAddress << EOF
command 1 #Execute in the remote
command 2 #Execute in the remote
bye
EOF
command 3 #Execute locally
```

As per my current knowledge of scripting, if a command fails to execute, the control simply passes to the next command. But what if the sftp command fails to establish a network connection in the above block? Does it mean `command 1` and `command 2` will be executed locally? Or will the control jump to `command 3`?

How do I catch a possible error in sftp and direct the control to `command 3`? And if that is possible, can I detect the error using the `?` variable, to take certain pre-emptive action? Some guidance will be great.

Comment: The contents of the here-document is not a part of shell commands, but a set of string(s) to be passed to the stdin of `sftp` and will be discarded if the connection fails. Then the control jumps to `command 3`.
The error codes of `sftp` is set to `$?`. Visit [here](https://support.microfocus.com/kb/doc.php?id=7021956) for the table of codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things to do.

First, you need to extract the input as a function, to allow piping with **command3**, and it will be more legible:

```
function sfpInstruction() {
cat << EOF
command 1
command 2
bye
EOF
}
```

Thus, your sftp instruction can be changed to:

```
tmpFile="/tmp/errorFile.txt"
sftp -i $IdentityFile $ServerAddress $( sfpInstruction ) 2>"$tmpFile" || command3
```

Such a way:

- all error messages are outpu in your error file
- in any case, if sftp exits with a failing status (NOT 0), GNU/Bash will execute command3
- if in addition you want command3 to read/check/parse the error messages, you can give it the **"$tmpFile"**